# Using for loop for calculating

Tags: python, for-loop

I am using a for loop to divide two lists such that first element of the 1st list divides with the first element of second list. Then I've appended the result to an empty list. Below is the code

```
def total_capital(df_balance):
    total_capital = []
    for i in range(0,5):
        cap = df_balance.ix[5,i]
        total_capital.append(cap)
    total_capital = [float(x) for x in total_capital]
    print('Total Capital is :')
    print(total_capital)
    print('-----------------------------------')
    net_income = []
    for i in range(0,5):
        net = df_income.ix[-1,i]
        net_income.append(net)
    print('Net Income is:')
    net_income = [float(x) for x in net_income]
    print(net_income)
    a = len(total_capital)
    b = len(net_income)
    roc = []
    for i in range(0,b):
        for j in range(0,a):
            ret = net_income[i]/total_capital[j]
        roc.append(ret)
    print('------------------------------------')
```

I am willing to divide elements of net_income with total_capital to generate a new list roc. But the output gives wrong results.

Here's the output:

```
Total Capital is :
[367560073.0, 306315566.0, 279233089.0, 272576179.0, 236272903.0]
-----------------------------------
Net Income is:
[28324711.0, 12887235.0, 6728637.0, 2620339.0, -9393534.0]
------------------------------------
roc is:
[0.11988133484777981, 0.054543855162265474, 0.028478242382284524, 0.011090306872811396, -0.03975713626373821]
```

Given the above result after calling function in python if I take the first element of both the list and divide them manually my answer does not match with the first element of list roc.

This is what I desired:

```
28324711.0 / 367560073.0 = 0.0770614467692741
```

This is what I got:

```
0.11988133484777981
```

Can anyone point out the error in above code which is causing this error.

Comment: I may be missing something, but first you set but you keep overwriting `ret` then add it to `roc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in range(0,b):
    for j in range(0,a):
        ret = net_income[i]/total_capital[j]
    roc.append(ret)
```

This doesn't look right to me. With two loops, you're dividing the first net income by the first total capital, then dividing the first net income by the second total capital, and so on, dividing every possible net income by every possible total capital. But most of those results are discarded. The only time you append to `ret` is when `j` is equal to a-1. So you're effectively only dividing by the final total capital. `28324711.0 / 236272903.0` equals `0.11988133484777981`, so this explains your output.

I'm guessing you want to iterate through the lists in parallel. Try:

```
for i in range(0,b):
    ret = net_income[i]/total_capital[i]
    roc.append(ret)
```

Or possibly:

```
for x,y in zip(net_income, total_capital):
    roc.append(x/y)
```

Or possibly:

```
roc = [x/y for x,y in zip(net_income, total_capital)]
```

---

It may be easier to understand the behavior of the original code by adding diagnostic printing information:

```
total_capital = [367560073.0, 306315566.0, 279233089.0, 272576179.0, 236272903.0]
net_income = [28324711.0, 12887235.0, 6728637.0, 2620339.0, -9393534.0]
a = len(total_capital)
b = len(net_income)
roc = []
for i in range(0,b):
    for j in range(0,a):
        print("calculating ret as the {}th net income divided by the {}th total capital".format(i,j))
        ret = net_income[i]/total_capital[j]
    print("appending to roc the value of the {}th net income divided by the {}th total capital".format(i,j))
    roc.append(ret)
```

Result:

```
calculating ret as the 0th net income divided by the 0th total capital
calculating ret as the 0th net income divided by the 1th total capital
calculating ret as the 0th net income divided by the 2th total capital
calculating ret as the 0th net income divided by the 3th total capital
calculating ret as the 0th net income divided by the 4th total capital
appending to roc the value of the 0th net income divided by the 4th total capital
calculating ret as the 1th net income divided by the 0th total capital
calculating ret as the 1th net income divided by the 1th total capital
calculating ret as the 1th net income divided by the 2th total capital
calculating ret as the 1th net income divided by the 3th total capital
calculating ret as the 1th net income divided by the 4th total capital
appending to roc the value of the 1th net income divided by the 4th total capital
calculating ret as the 2th net income divided by the 0th total capital
calculating ret as the 2th net income divided by the 1th total capital
calculating ret as the 2th net income divided by the 2th total capital
calculating ret as the 2th net income divided by the 3th total capital
calculating ret as the 2th net income divided by the 4th total capital
appending to roc the value of the 2th net income divided by the 4th total capital
calculating ret as the 3th net income divided by the 0th total capital
calculating ret as the 3th net income divided by the 1th total capital
calculating ret as the 3th net income divided by the 2th total capital
calculating ret as the 3th net income divided by the 3th total capital
calculating ret as the 3th net income divided by the 4th total capital
appending to roc the value of the 3th net income divided by the 4th total capital
calculating ret as the 4th net income divided by the 0th total capital
calculating ret as the 4th net income divided by the 1th total capital
calculating ret as the 4th net income divided by the 2th total capital
calculating ret as the 4th net income divided by the 3th total capital
calculating ret as the 4th net income divided by the 4th total capital
appending to roc the value of the 4th net income divided by the 4th total capital
```

You can see that the only time anything is ever appended to `roc`, it's using the 4th total capital. No other value from total capital is used for values appended to `roc`.

Now, adding the same diagnostic information to my suggested solution:

```
total_capital = [367560073.0, 306315566.0, 279233089.0, 272576179.0, 236272903.0]
net_income = [28324711.0, 12887235.0, 6728637.0, 2620339.0, -9393534.0]
a = len(total_capital)
b = len(net_income)
roc = []
for i in range(0,b):
    print("calculating ret as the {}th net income divided by the {}th total capital".format(i,i))
    ret = net_income[i]/total_capital[i]
    print("appending to roc the value of the {}th net income divided by the {}th total capital".format(i,i))
    roc.append(ret)
```

Gives a more sensible result:

```
calculating ret as the 0th net income divided by the 0th total capital
appending to roc the value of the 0th net income divided by the 0th total capital
calculating ret as the 1th net income divided by the 1th total capital
appending to roc the value of the 1th net income divided by the 1th total capital
calculating ret as the 2th net income divided by the 2th total capital
appending to roc the value of the 2th net income divided by the 2th total capital
calculating ret as the 3th net income divided by the 3th total capital
appending to roc the value of the 3th net income divided by the 3th total capital
calculating ret as the 4th net income divided by the 4th total capital
appending to roc the value of the 4th net income divided by the 4th total capital
```

Now all values from total capital are used in `roc`.

Comment: Tried the first solution worked perfectly.  Thanks for pointing out the error.